# Why does the value of a variable changes on appending to python list as a list?

Tags: python, debugging, numpy, vector

In the code below if I change `sim.append(similarity(doc,query))` in the function `similarityForCorpus(documentList,query)` to `sim.append([similarity(doc,query),doc])` or `sim.append((similarity(doc,query),doc))` the value printed for `similarity(doc,query)` by the last statement changes by a small amount and I don't know why that happens and how could it be corrected ?

```
#python code to calculate similarity of two equal sized vectors

#global variables and libraries
import numpy as np
sim=[]

#returns cosine similairty of two vectors
def similarity(document,query):
    vectorA=np.array(document)
    vectorB=np.array(query)
    return np.dot(vectorA,vectorB)/(np.linalg.norm(vectorA)*np.linalg.norm(vectorB))


#calculate document and query similarities for all documents in corpus
def similarityForCorpus(documentList,query):
    global sim
    for doc in documentList:
        sim.append(similarity(doc,query))

similarityForCorpus([[3,4,5],[0,8,10]],[3,4,5])

#rank similarities highest to lowest
sim.sort(reverse=True)

#print similarities
for s in sim:
    print s
```

Comment: They are the same. I don't have the link, but you're just seeing floating point imprecisions, which tend to show more clearly in Python than in quite a few other languages. Just look at the differences between the numbers, then look at the floating point precision of your system (e.g. `sys.float_info.epsilon`).

Comment: @Evert I also thought the same thing but you see I will be using the values for a naive implementation of GVSM model to rank the documents based on similarity, so won't that ranking be affected by these imprecisions, and the main questions is that why is that change of value reflected in the second case and not the first one ?

Comment: I don't know ranking or GVSM, but I'm pretty sure you're just limited by machine precision. Have you checked the numbers for accuracy? You will have to compare (for similarity) with a certain precision anyway.

Comment: As to why the difference in output: I don't know. You would have to dig into Pythons (or numpy) engine to find out why a `np.float64` is printed differently on its own versus when printed inside a list or tuple. Again, don't rely on the `str()` version of a float, only rely on (within accuracy) its actual value.

Comment: @Evert ok let's take it in a simple way don't you think the output of sort will be erroneous if two values are very close, because of this imprecision and is there some way to overcome that ?

Comment: sort: no, this is *exactly* what you get at machine precision: if two values are that close, they are the same within machine precision, and thus sorting doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: If you're *really, really* keen on working with such detail, you either have to rethink your problem and algorithm, or find another library that can do this. But I think you may want to rethink your perception of precision here first.

Comment: You can check for equality and take it from there. If inequal your expectation they there is a quantifiable dissimilarity. I am rather sure this is the part of the code that writes out the numbers, and not the numbers themself. try: "{:e}".format(x) for verify they are indeed the same numbers.

Comment: @Dabrion: better is probably `x.hex()`: that will tell you whether the computer considers two floating point values the same, since they have the same hexadecimal (and thus binary) representation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're looking at the same value in two different ways. The two `print` functions are not behaving the same way. One of them is given a floating point value and the other a tupple.

The values are exactly the same, but non of them are exactly what you want. Check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) link, it explains what's happening.

Also for your code, check this out:

```
#global variables and libraries
import numpy as np

#returns cosine similairty of two vectors
def similarity(document,query):
    vectorA=np.array(document)
    vectorB=np.array(query)
    return np.dot(vectorA,vectorB)/(np.linalg.norm(vectorA)*np.linalg.norm(vectorB))


#calculate document and query similarities for all documents in corpus
def similarityForCorpus(documentList,query):
    global sim
    for doc in documentList:
        sim.append([similarity(doc,query),doc])

sim=[]
similarityForCorpus([[3,4,5],[0,8,10]],[3,4,5])

#rank similarities highest to lowest
sim.sort(reverse=True)

#print similarities
for s in sim:
    print('%0.16f %s' % (s[0], s[1]))


def similarityForCorpus(documentList,query):
    global sim
    for doc in documentList:
        sim.append(similarity(doc,query))

sim=[]
similarityForCorpus([[3,4,5],[0,8,10]],[3,4,5])

#rank similarities highest to lowest
sim.sort(reverse=True)

for s in sim:
    print('%0.16f' % (s))
```

The output will be:

```
0.9999999999999999 [3, 4, 5]
0.9055385138137416 [0, 8, 10]
0.9999999999999999
0.9055385138137416
```

Answer (score 2):

The number stored is the same in both cases. The only difference is what is being printed. Consider this:

```
>>> a=1.234567890123456789
>>> print a
1.23456789012
>>> print [a]
[1.2345678901234567]
```

In the first case, the equivalent of `str(a)` is invoked, which does not show the full precision. In the second case, `repr(a)` is used.